# How to add all dependencies/libraries in a repository with R code

Tags: r, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm building an application using [quarto](https://quarto.org), which has both python and R code parts in it, and I'm deploying all the code in a git repository. The project logic is run from a main.py file, which in turn executes some python scripts, some R scripts and eventually renders the quarto documents. I'm aware of the practice of using a `requirements.txt` file for all the modules used in a python virtual environment, when creating a public repository and pushing changes of the projects to it. I was wondering if there were something similar R-wise, especially something that would come in handy when handling the project inside an IDE such as `RStudio`.

This is what I would want, to let someone clone my repository and get all the necessary dependencies:

1. [Dump all dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file]
2. [Open R-Studio terminal]
3. [Create R virtual environment]
4. [Use a `requirements.txt` to install the necessary dependencies within the environment]

Comment: Check out [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html): _The renv package is a new effort to bring project-local R dependency management to your projects_ . You get a json with the packages and dependencies similar to a Python poetry .toml (which I think is slightly preferable to pip) or npm package-lock.json.